# I can not replace the text in a html body that comes from the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, replace

I want to replace the text `'$$$_img1_$$$'` with a `p` tag that will come from the database

```js
$("body").children().each(function() {

    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('$$$_img1_$$$', variable_name));
});


$("body").children().each(function() {

    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('$$$_img1_$$$', "hahahhah"));
});
```

If the `variable_name` contains a `img` tag
then the `'$$$_img1_$$$'` will be replaced with the image tag `<img src = ''>`

Comment: add full html string in fiddle and share a link

Comment: Can you post an exampled of data and desired result, please? I can't understand you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('body').each(function() {
   var replaced = $("body").html().replace('$$$_img1_$$$','The ALL new string');
   $("body").html(replaced);
});
```